# Open different ViewControllers from the same TableViewCell (Like facebook notifications)

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

Here's the issue, I'm trying to make an app that receives updates for different data in the same TableView (like facebook, lets say), that's not the issue however. All data has the same format, the thing is when you click on a row I want to open the corresponding view, I can identify the correct view to display. I try to use the following.

> NavigationController.PushViewController (DestinationViewController, false);

When it gets triggered the objects that I created on the storyboard for the DestinationViewController appear to be null, and all the "glue" code is on the ViewDidLoad or ViewWillAppears (which is supposed to have every object instantiated)

I'm using Tab Bar Navigation Model.

PS: If I use the app and enter to my DestinationViewController it works.

So who knows an approach or has an example of something like this, or something that will get me near the place i want to go?

Comment: What code do you have in your `prepareForSegue` for your table view scene?

Comment: Mmmm, i'm using the RowSelected from the TableSource to handle clicks on the row of the tableview, i don't know if i can put multiple segues  on the same TableViewCell, in fact actualy XCode Interface Builder does not allow me to link more than one segue per element ( i think), so im not using the PrepareForSegue method of the ViewController, should i used it?

Comment: Which ever method you are using you need to show the code where you set the property for the new viewcontroller that holds your object reference for the selected cells object. You mentioned a storyboard, so I presume that you are triggering segues, which means that prepareForSegue is where you get access to the destination view controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the issue kinda like Michael and Paul, says.

Declare a public Attribute on the ViewController.

Then passed the current ViewController to the table source, on the RowSelected Method i put the selected value on the public property of the viewController

And in the PrepareForSegue method i check which type of data it is so i can assign the appropiate segue on the segue.DestinationViewController and pass the data.

I don't know if this is the best approach but, it works good.

Answer (score 1):

If you use

```
NavigationController.PushViewController (DestinationViewController, false);
```

I believe you need to allocate the view controller before you use it with

```
DestinationVC *vc = [DestinationVC alloc] init];
```

Correct me if im wrong everyone.

Also if you are using storyboards and have control dragged to different views, you should use the method

```
[self.navigationController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"" sender:self];
```

Then you can use the prepareForSegue method.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"whatYouNamedItInTheStoryboard"]) {
        // do stuff for this segue
    } else if ([segue identifier] isEqual.......) {

    }
}
```

Hopefully this helps your problem. 
You might want to post an image of your storyboard.